# What is the exact meaning / purpose of the J and R flags in jshell?

Tags: runtime, java-9, jshell

From the help information:

```
-J<flag>              Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system.
                      Use one -J for each runtime flag or flag argument
-R<flag>              Pass <flag> to the remote runtime system.
                      Use one -R for each remote flag or flag argument
```

I cannot find an explanation in both the [tools documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/toc.htm) and [jshell user guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm).

Also, what is "the remote runtime system" in the context of jshell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I understand it, JShell has 3 main 'places' to execute code:

- In the current process (see [DirectExecutionControl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/execution/DirectExecutionControl.html))
- In the same JVM as the JShell client (see [LocalExecutionControl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/execution/LocalExecutionControl.html))
- On the remote agent (see [JdiDefaultExecutionControl](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/execution/JdiDefaultExecutionControl.html))

Using `jshell` tool, we have no *current* process before launch, so we have only two options - use one JVM (locally), or use two JVMs - one for JShell client (locally) and another for the execution engine (possibly remotely).

The interesting thing is, JShell always launch two JVMs by default, as the hard-coded *--execution* key is `"failover:0(jdi:hostname(" + loopback + ")),1(jdi:launch(true)), 2(jdi)"` (see [JShell](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/JShell.html) class source code).

Closer to the point. I've made a couple of experiments with `-verbose` option and checked JVM options in runtime with `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments()`.

- `jshell -J-verbose` command

  Printed `-verbose` output in the console.

  No `-verbose` option in the input arguments: `[-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:63305]`
- `jshell -R-verbose` command

  No `-verbose` output in the console.

  Printed `-verbose` option in the input arguments: `[-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:63339, -verbose]`
- `jshell --execution="local" -J-verbose` command

  Printed `-verbose` output in the console.

  Printed `-verbose` option in the input arguments: `[-Dapplication.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9, -Xms8m, -verbose, -Djdk.module.main=jdk.jshell]`
- `jshell --execution="local" -R-verbose`

  No `-verbose` output in the console.

  No `-verbose` option in the input arguments: `[-Dapplication.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9, -Xms8m, -Djdk.module.main=jdk.jshell]`

#### TL;DR

#### Remote execution (default case, execution over JDI)

`-J<flag>` passes option to the **JShell client** JVM

`-R<flag>` passes option to the **execution engine** JVM

#### Local execution (--execution="local")

`-J<flag>` passes option to the **only present** JVM

`-R<flag>` does nothing

Comment: Wow, I am really impressed by your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I still find the scope of explaining the usage of the flags used in both the attributes for the question to be answered completely, hence putting that in words here.

➜ `-J` flag is used to provide a *runtime argument* to the JShell which is similar to the way one provides while performing via an IDE under *Run -> Configuration* to specify arguments as `-Dkey=value`.

The usage of the attribute is documented and quite similar to ones illustrated for the [flag `-C`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46741579/1746118) just that the -J flags are instead the [`java` command line options](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/java.htm#GUID-3B1CE181-CD30-4178-9602-230B800D4FAE__BABDJJFI). 
For example, using the `-XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags` would detail out the runtime flags used by the current JVM.

So, the default values of command line flags used by your JShell instance(without setting any additional flag) could be as:-

[image]

But let's say you don't want to make use of the `CompactStrings` of Java9 in your JShell execution you can tell the JVM using the `-J` flag and `-XX:-CompactStrings` attribute to do so, as -

```
jshell -R-XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -R-XX:-CompactStrings
```

would list out the following output:

[image]

➜ Similar `java` command line options/flags, when attached with and used to start JShell on a remote JVM, are linked to `-R` attribute of the JShell during remote execution.

```
jshell -R-XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -R-XX:-CompactStrings
```

---

Anatoly's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408157/1746118) has got some good amount of research attached to it and I would suggest that to be read to understand about control and execution engine of the JShell for local Vs remote execution.