# What is the use of C option in jshell

Tags: java, java-9, jshell

I have gone through the [introduction to jshell guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/jshell/introduction-jshell.htm#JSHEL-GUID-630F27C8-1195-4989-9F6B-2C51D46F52C8) and couldn't find description/examples about the -C option in jshell.

```
$jshell --help
 -C<flag>              Pass <flag> to the compiler.
                        Use one -C for each compiler flag or flag argument
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this option to make use of [`javac` command line arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__BHCJEIBB) for example consider this piece of code:

```
String str = (String)"Hello"
```

Starting `jshell` normally and using the same would result as:

[image]

---

While at the same time you can enable compiler errors on warning(`-Werror`) and make use of the `-Xlint` key `cast` while compiling to warn you of the explicit cast used in the above code using -

```
jshell -C-Xlint:cast -C-Werror
```

and the same statement would result into warnings and error from Jshell compiler as:-

[image]

---

Though IMO, this certainly is documented far less in terms of what all flags shall/shall not be used while using the JShell `-C` command line option.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for such a detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

To pass options to the `javac` compiler that `jshell` is going to run to compile the statements in your REPL. One simple example (to see which classes are loaded), `jshell -C-verbose`. See also [Standard Options for javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__STANDARDOPTIONSFORJAVAC-7D3D9CC2) and [Extra Options for javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javac.htm#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9__NONSTANDARDOPTIONSFORJAVAC-7D3DAA9D) for additional options you might specify.

Comment: Not very sure of all the javac options. I tried `jshell -C-version` for instance and it resulted into `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid flag: -version`

Comment: @nullpointer True, of course `-version` prints the version and exits; so supporting it wouldn't make much sense. I was simply trying to answer as to the purpose of the `-C` option.

Comment: Ya, even I thought it's worth mentioning the same. And there is no clear documentation around what all flags categorize themselves to be used by Jshell as well.

Comment: Since these arguments are being passed to the compiler that is used to compile snippets, inappropriate options can cause JShell to fail.

Comment: @RobertField I assume its the same case with [J and R Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399679/what-is-the-exact-meaning-purpose-of-the-j-and-r-flags-in-jshell?noredirect=1&lq=1) as well?