# How to pass arguments to a jshell script?

Tags: java-9, jshell

### Question

I am willing to pass arguments to a jshell script. For instance, I would have liked something like this:

```
jshell myscript.jsh "some text"
```

and then to have the string "some text" available in some variable inside the script.

However, `jshell` only expects a list of files, therefore the answer is:

```
File 'some text' for 'jshell' is not found.
```

Is there any way to properly pass arguments to a jshell script?

### Workaround so far

My only solution so far is to use an environment variable when calling the script:

```
ARG="some test" jshell myscript.jsh
```

And then I can access it in the script with:

```
System.getenv().get("ARG")
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

And what about option `-R`

```
> jshell -v -R-Da=b ./file.jsh
```

for script

```
{
  String value = System.getProperty("a");
  System.out.println("a="+value);
}
/exit
```

will give you

```
> jshell -v -R-Da=b ./file.jsh
a=b
```

Another way, would be following:

```
{
  class A {
    public void main(String args[])
    {
        for(String arg : args) {
          System.out.println(arg);
        }
    }
  }

  new A().main(System.getProperty("args").split(" "));
}
```

and execution

```
> jshell -R-Dargs="aaa bbb ccc" ./file_2.jsh
```

***Update***

Previous solution will fail with more complex args. E.g. `'This is my arg'`.

But we can benefit from `ant` and it's `CommandLine` class

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.types.Commandline;
{
  class A {
    public void main(String args[])
    {
      for(String arg : args) {
        System.out.println(arg);
      }
    }
  }

  new A().main(Commandline.translateCommandline(System.getProperty("args")));
}
```

and then, we can call it like this:

```
jshell --class-path ./ant.jar -R-Dargs="aaa 'Some args with spaces' bbb ccc" ./file_2.jsh
aaa
Some args with spaces
bbb
ccc
```

Of course, `ant.jar` must be in the path that is passed via `--class-path`

Comment: Interesting! I has tried to use `-R` but I had not understood its syntax correctly. This is still far from perfect, but avoids binding environment variables for nothing. Thanks!

Comment: -R passes arguments to Runtime Environment. So, what you see here i passing -Dkey=val to JVM. As a result you have key with value inside properties.

Comment: I have a doubt though, why not [`-J` instead of `-R`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399679/what-is-the-exact-meaning-purpose-of-the-j-and-r-flags-in-jshell)?

Comment: @nullpointer `-R' is for the execution engine and is the correct option as explained in the accepted answer to that question. (I also verified that it works with R and not with J)

Comment: @Oleg I agree it doesn't work with `-J`, but the TLDR part of the answer specifies that the *Local execution (--execution="local") `-J<flag>` passes option to the only present JVM* while `-R` does nothing. Isn't the execution local now?

Comment: @nullpointer No, by default it's not local, 2 processes are created. As I said Oracle really screwed this up.

Comment: @Oleg Could you better explain or add some link to proof about *Oracle really screwed this up*...not able to get what do you mean there?

Comment: @nullpointer Not much to explain, this is just my personal opinion. Not giving good option to pass arguments to the shell and starting 2 processes by default(causing confusion between `J` and `R`) to me means screwing it up. If you think that they did a good job then that's fine.

Comment: @Oleg And could you detail *No, by default it's not local, 2 processes are created.* as well please.

Comment: @nullpointer It's in the question you linked to... https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408157/1398418

Comment: @Oleg I believe you are misunderstanding that. It never mentioned about *2 processes*, but *2 options left*.

Comment: @nullpointer `use **two**(why it's not bold inside backticks???) JVMs - one for JShell client (locally) and another for the execution engine` from the TL;DR `Remote execution (**default** case, execution over JDI)` I also verified it myself. By default 2 processes are created `JShellToolProvider` and `RemoteExecutionControl` when you pass the `--execution="local"` local option only `JShellToolProvider` is created.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle really screwed this up, there is no good way to do this. In addition to [@mko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46756841/1398418) and if you use Linux(probably will work on Mac too) you can use [process substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/64011).

```
jshell <(echo 'String arg="some text"') myscript.jsh
```

And then you can just use `arg` in `myscript.jsh` for example:

```
System.out.println(arg) // will print "some text"
```

You can simplify it with some bash function and probably write a batch file that will write to a temp file and do the same on windows.

Comment: isn't this platform dependent even when it might work. Also not sure what your myscript.jsh contents are/

Comment: @nullpointer `myscript.jsh` is from OP's question doesn't really matter what are the contents but if you're curious you can ask OP about it. Your first sentence is already addressed in the answer.

Comment: What the solution suggested by you does is, edit the script altogether. instead of passing a value to a variable as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @nullpointer No it passes the value, `arg` can be used in `myscript.jsh` this is what OP wanted. It should be before it though, fixed, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's completely beyond me how Oracle could ignore this. 8-() But anyway: if your system uses bash as shell, you can combine [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44916618/how-to-execute-a-java-script-with-jshell) replacing the shebang with the idea to [(ab-)use system properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46756841/21499) to transport the whole command line into a variable:

```
//usr/bin/env jshell --execution local "-J-Da=$*" "$0"; exit $?
String commandline = System.getProperty("a");
System.out.println(commandline);
/exit
```

This way, you can call the script on the commandline simply adding the arguments: `thisscript.jsh arg1  arg2` would print `arg1 arg2`.

Please note that this joins all parameters into one String, separated by one space. You can split it again with `commandline.split("\s")`, but please be aware that this isn't exact: there is no difference between two parameters `a b` and one parameter `"a   b"`.

If you have a fixed number of arguments, you can also pass all of these into separate system properties with `"-J-Darg1=$1" "-J-Darg2=$1" "-J-Darg3=$1"` etc. Please observe that you have to use `-R-D...` if you are not using [`--execution local`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46408157/21499)

Another variant is generating the script on the fly with bash's [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46760071/21499). You can use such a script also simply as `thisscript.jsh arg1  arg2` also on Unix-like systems having a bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
jshell <(
cat <<EOF
System.out.println("$1");
System.out.println("$2");
/exit
EOF
)
```

This allows to access individual parameters, though it will break when there are double quotes or other special characters in a parameter. Expanding on that idea: here's a way to put all parameters into an Java String array, quoting some of those characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -- "${@//\\/\\\\}"
set -- "${@//\"/\\\"}"
set -- "${@/#/\"}"
set -- "${@/%/\",}"
jshell <(
cat <<EOF
String[] args = new String[]{$@};
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(args));
/exit
EOF
)
```

The `set --` statements double backslashes, quote double quotes and prefix a `"` and append a `",` to transform the arguments into a valid Java array.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I was inspired by answers from Oleg and Hans-Peter Störr enough to try to combine them so that a) I could use normal shell arguments b) write regular Java code expecting a `String[] args` input:

```
//usr/bin/env jshell <(ARGS=; for var in "$@"; do ARGS+="\"$var\","; done; echo "String[] args = {$ARGS}") "$0"; exit $?

System.out.println("RESULT: " + Arrays.asList(args));

/exit
```

Using Hans' header line and then inlining as demonstrated by Oleg which builds the $@ args into a `String[] args` var.

With that you can `chmod +x` your script and execute it with regular old arguments:

```
]$ ./script.jsh foo bar
RESULT: [test, bar]
```