# How to take user input in jshell script?

Tags: java-9, jshell

### Question:

How to take user input in **jshell script**? or what I'm doing wrong?

*Note:* I'm **NOT** looking [how to pass arguments to jshell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756421/how-to-pass-arguments-to-a-jshell-script).

#### Example:

For example script `hello.java`:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter number n1: ");
int n1 = in.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter number n2: ");
int n2 = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("n1 + n2 = "+ (n1 +n2));

/exit
```

It works if I type line by line in jshell, but then I run `jshell hello.java` it doesn't. Throws `java.util.NoSuchElementException`.

**Output I getting:**

```
@myMint ~/Java $ jshell hello.java 
Enter number n1: |  java.util.NoSuchElementException thrown: 
|        at Scanner.throwFor (Scanner.java:858)
|        at Scanner.next (Scanner.java:1497)
|        at Scanner.nextInt (Scanner.java:2161)
|        at Scanner.nextInt (Scanner.java:2115)
|        at (#3:1)
Enter number n2: |  java.util.NoSuchElementException thrown: 
|        at Scanner.throwFor (Scanner.java:858)
|        at Scanner.next (Scanner.java:1497)
|        at Scanner.nextInt (Scanner.java:2161)
|        at Scanner.nextInt (Scanner.java:2115)
|        at (#5:1)
n1 + n2 = 0
```

My system: *Linux Mint 18.2(x64), JShell Version 9.0.1*

Comment: Two ways to look at it. One if I consider the input in the script after `int n1 = in.nextInt();` as entered by you manually. Another what happens if you remove those Return(enter) from the scripts and run it as a single line with statements separated by semi-colon? But interestingly the comparison of script vs line by line is good to see the difference here and not to forget `throws NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted`

Comment: @nullpointer I was thinking about first way. Adding `in.hasNextLine()` [check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13729470/5322506) (tnx for pointing it) get rid of exception. But now feels like I need some kind of pause(hold until the user enters)..?? Second way... I'm a student(not native English speaker) and it gave my brain "little" what the hell I just read. I read your post few times, think what I just read, try single line script (results was same), read your post again, think again... and still feel lost. Did I miss smth?   BTW thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per default, `jshell` delegates execution to a remote VM. If you pass `--execution local` it uses the same VM process, which provides an instance of `System.in` as expected. Tailored to your question, the following call should do the trick:

```
jshell --execution local hello.java
```

See details via `jshell --help-extra` or browse the API documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jshell/module-summary.html

Comment: This is what I needed.

Comment: seems with `--execution local`, it will ignore `--classPath` parameters. not sure why

Comment: Prepending a `-J` should do the trick. See `jshell --help` and its manual for help, especially regarding `-J`, `-R`, and `-C` options.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this issue, but not directly with JShell based code.

There is this project `jshell_script_executor`: https://github.com/kotari4u/jshell_script_executor

You can download it, and with small modification inside `JShellScriptExecutor.java`

from

```
try(JShell jshell = JShell.create()){
```

to

```
// This call will map System.in in your main code
// to System.in inside JShell evaluated code
try(JShell jshell =
  JShell.builder()
    .in(System.in)
    .out(System.out)
    .err(System.err)
    .build()){
```

and (also) small modification of your code (I know this is not exactly what you are looking for - we don't use Scanner here):

```
/* Put this code into file.jshell */
import java.io.*;

InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
int n1;
System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
n1 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

int n2;
System.out.print("Enter the number: ");
n2 = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

System.out.println("n1 + n2 = " + (n1 + n2));
```

you can get it running:

```
> javac src/main/java/com/sai/jshell/extension/JShellScriptExecutor.java
> java -cp src/main/java com.sai.jshell.extension.JShellScriptExecutor ./file.jshell
Enter the number: 1
Enter the number: 2
n1 + n2 = 3
```

Well ... in fact it will work with your code as well - slightly modified:

```
/* Put this code into file_scanner.java */
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter number n1: ");
int n1 = in.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter number n2: ");
int n2 = in.nextInt();

System.out.println("n1 + n2 = "+ (n1 +n2));
```

and give it a try

```
> java -cp src/main/java com.sai.jshell.extension.JShellScriptExecutor ./file_scanner.java
Enter number n1: 1
Enter number n2: 2
n1 + n2 = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

From JDK11 you can directly execute java source file:

```
$java Script.java
```

See [Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/330)